# Error when adding data on top of each bar

Tags: chart.js

I need to put the value of each bar of **Chart.JS** on top of it. And here is the script:

```
    var areaChartData = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"
      , "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Cash Income",
          strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data: costData
        }
      ]
    };
    var barChartCanvas = $("#barChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var barChart = new Chart(barChartCanvas);
    var barChartData = areaChartData;
    barChartData.datasets[0].fillColor = "#00c0ef";
    barChartData.datasets[0].strokeColor = "#00c0ef";
    barChartData.datasets[0].pointColor = "#00a65a";
    var barChartOptions = {
      //Boolean - Whether the scale should start at zero, or an order of magnitude down from the lowest value
      scaleBeginAtZero: true,
      //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
      scaleShowGridLines: true,
      //String - Colour of the grid lines
      scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
      //Number - Width of the grid lines
      scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
      //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
      scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
      //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
      scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
      //Boolean - If there is a stroke on each bar
      barShowStroke: true,
      //Number - Pixel width of the bar stroke
      barStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Number - Spacing between each of the X value sets
      barValueSpacing: 5,
      //Number - Spacing between data sets within X values
      barDatasetSpacing: 1,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
      //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,

      onAnimationComplete: function () {

      var barChartData = this.chart.barChartData;
      barChartData.font = this.scale.font;
      barChartData.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
      barChartData.textAlign = "center";
      barChartData.textBaseline = "bottom";

      this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
          dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
             barChartData.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
          });
        })
      }
    };

    barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
    barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
  }
```

And I always get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'font' of undefined

[image]

I am new to **Chart.JS** and don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is in your `onAnimationComplete` function. `this.chart.barChartData` is `undefined` which is why the code starts to fail.

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but if you were to remove those lines that try to edit the undefined properties you will no longer receive the error. But like I say it is unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve so apart from this I do not know what to suggest.

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/f3oec1rL/

you do have access to the options `this.options` and the datasets `this.datasets` if you wanted to set something in them?